# Move WhatsApp media data to SD card

Tags: sd-card, whatsapp-messenger, link2sd

My WhatsApp folder (/data/media/0/WhatsApp) and in particular its media folder has grown very much. So I want to move it to my SD card. I have rooted my Samsung Galaxy S4 and created an ext4 partition on my SD card for the Link2SD app. However, when I use Link2SD to link WhatsApp to the ext4 partition, it only moves the WhatsApp app but not its data folder with the media which contains most data.

I have also tried to move the WhatsApp folder in a terminal app and softlink to it. However, then WhatsApp stops working and crashes on start.

Is there a way to move the WhatsApp data to an SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a rooted phone for this.

1. Download FolderMount.
2. Create a new folder in the external memory where you want the media to be stored.
3. Open FolderMount and add a new entry. Give it any name you like. Whatsapp media here.
4. In the source, specify the path of default whatsapp folder of your internal memory.
5. In the destination, specify the the new folder you created in your external memory card.
6. Done. Also, select 'exclude from mediascan' if you don't want duplicate items to be seen in the gallery or music player.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time tested it yet, but it sounds like it works!